# Mercurial config: merge-patterns working on `hg update`

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc

In my .hgrc I have this merge pattern defined:

```
[merge-patterns]
public_html/** =internal:other
```

When i run `hg merge <branch_name>` the mergetool still tries to merge al the (generated) files under public_html, which causes to crash my difftool and causes a whole lot of other merge problems.

When I fix those problems and run `hg resolve --all` the merge pattern DOES seem to be respected (but that could also be because I fixed some problems by hand). Why is my merge pattern not working (on a merge)?